# Poincaré optimal constant under multiple conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ be the unit square, $\Gamma_1=[0,1]\times\{0;1\}$ its horizontal boundary and  $\Gamma_2= \{0;1\}\times[0,1]$ its vertical boundary.

I would like to know the *optimal* Poincaré constants $C$, defined by
$$
\forall u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)\quad \int_\Omega u^2\le C\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2,
$$

under these conditions (separately):

i) $u|_{\Gamma_1}=0$;

ii)  $u|_{\Gamma_1}=0$ *and* $u$ has zero average: $\int_\Omega u=0 $.

*Updated part*:

I *presume* that in the first case the optimal constant is $1/\pi^2$, if I correctly interpreted the method for finding it (as eigenvalue of the laplacian), realized by the function $u(x,y)=\sin(\pi y) $. In the second case I think it could be $1/2\pi^2$, realized by $u(x,y)=\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi y) $.

iii) $u|_{\Gamma_1}=0$,  $u$ has zero average: $\int_\Omega u=0$ and $u$ is periodic at boundary $\Gamma_2$, i.e. $u(0,y)=u(1,y) $

In this case I guess the constant is $1/4\pi^2$, realized by $u(x,y)= \sin(2\pi y) $ (in fact, the function $u(x,y)=\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi y) $ is not $x$-periodic at $\Gamma_2$).

Answer (score 2):

(I only answer here case i)

For any closed subspace $V\subset H^1(\Omega)$, the eigenvalues $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\ldots$ of the positive Laplacian in $V$ satisfy
$$
\lambda_k=\min_{H_{k-1}}\rho,
$$
where the *Rayleigh quotient* is
$$
\rho(u)=\frac{\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2}{\|u\|_{L^2}^2},
$$
and the orthogonal complement of the first $k-1$ eigenspaces is
$$
H_{k-1}=\{u\in V:\langle u,u_j\rangle=0,j=1,\ldots,k-1\}.
$$
Moreover, if $u\in H_{k-1}$ and $\rho(u)=\lambda_k$ then $-\Delta u=\lambda_ku$.
See, for example, page 16 of [these notes](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f18/laplacenotes.pdf).

This immediately implies that 
$$
\lambda_k\|u\|_{L^2}^2\leq\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2
\qquad\textrm{for all} \quad
u\in H_{k-1},
$$
and $\lambda_k$ is the largest possible constant. So the optimal $C$ is simply
$$
C=\frac1{\lambda_k}.
$$
What we need to do now is identify the spaces $V$ and $H_{k-1}$, and compute $\lambda_k$.

**Case i)** In this case, we take $V=\{u\in H^1(\Omega):u|_{\Gamma_1}=0\}$ as the underlying space, and $k=1$, so that $H_{k-1}=H_0=V$. Each of the functions
$$
\begin{split}
&\sin(m\pi x)\sin(n\pi y),\qquad m=1,2,\ldots,\quad n=1,2,\ldots\\
&\cos(m\pi x)\sin(n\pi y)\qquad m=0,1,\ldots,\quad n=1,2,\ldots,
\end{split}
$$
is in $V$, and satisfy $-\Delta u = \lambda u$ with $\lambda=\pi^2(m^2+n^2)$.
Moreover, completeness of this orthogonal set can be shown by using Fubini's theorem as in Example 26 of the [same notes](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f18/laplacenotes.pdf). Thus there are no other eigenfunctions.
The smallest eigenvalue occurs at $m=0$ and $n=1$:
$$
\lambda_1=\pi^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found interesting also the reference. I would like to see the solution also for the cases ii) and iii). I guess that it follows by identifying $V$ with the suitable $H_k$  in each case.

Comment: Please let me know if you figure out how to handle those cases. I left them out because I could not see a straightforward way to fit them into the framework, as there is no constant eigenfunction in the Dirichlet case and so the zero average condition cannot be written as orthogonality to some eigenfunction.

Comment: In fact, I have not a precise idea of how doing that; in fact, that was the point of my question. If I will be able I'll write my attempt.